# What is the scope of json variable outside the function in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, json, scope

Consider the below code snippet,

```
 function(){
    if(condition){
      var json = { "stat":"success","count":"3" };
    }
 }
 console.log(json);
 return json;
```

Here json should not give values right as its scope has been already ended, but I could get the json values actually. Can anybody tell me how this works?

Comment: Your code does not make any sense as it's not legal Javascript.  Your function doesn't have a name or any way to execute it.  You don't show any caller of the function.  And, `console.log(json)` would create an arrow because there is no `json` variable in that scope.  Please clean up your example to something that would actually run so we can tell what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is something like this (code that would actually run):

```
 function test(){
    if(condition){
      var json = { "stat":"success","count":"3" };
    }
    console.log(json);
    return json;
 }

 test();
```

You are using `var`.  `var` creates a variable that has function scope, not block scope.  Therefore your code is equivalent to this:

```
 function test(){
    var json = undefined;           // variable is function scoped
    if(condition){
      json = { "stat":"success","count":"3" };
    }
    console.log(json);              // can access here, may have undefined value
    return json;
 }

 test();
```

If you uses `let` or `const` instead of `var`, then your variable would be block scoped and this would create an error:

```
 function test(){
    if(condition){
      let json = { "stat":"success","count":"3" };
    }
    console.log(json);
    return json;
 }

 test();
```

because the `json` variable declared with `const` or `let` is ONLY available within the block scope that you created it in and both the `console.log(json)` and the `return json` would both create errors for trying to reference a variable that no longer exists.